# Where is index.html for IIS7?

Tags: windows, iis-7, web-server, directory

I have enabled IIS7 in Windows 7. It works fine. I can see the default page from my local computer as well as from remote computer connected to the Internet.

Now I would like to do something. I would like to change my index.html. Does anybody know where this file can be located?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have a look at the basic settings of the Default Web Site; this is where the physical path for the site root is defined.

This is by default `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually within C:\inetpub (replacing C:\ with the system path letter)